# How to return a default attribute for a class' instance?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class with the following structure:

```python
class Example:
    def __init__(self, value, foo):
        self.value = value
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = self.modify_stuff(value, foo)

    def modify_stuff(self, value, foo):
        """ some code """
        pass
```

I want to create an instance of the class, and then be able to refer to `value` directly, like this:

```python
ex = Example(3, 'foo')
ans = 5 + ex
```

Instead of:

```python
ans = 5 + ex.value
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Python doesn't do implicit conversions, period. [It's literally in the zen](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/). The best you can do is manually implement `__add__`/`__radd__`/etc to have the appropriate behavior

Comment: @Brian, but what about `pandas.DataFrame`? if I create something like `df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4])` I can access the data directly from `df` (like `df + 5`), I don't need to do something like `df.data + 5`

Comment: Yes, because pandas manually implemented `__add__`/`__radd__`/etc to have the appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the **add** and **radd**:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Example):
            return self.value + other.value

        return self.value + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Example):
            return self.value + other.value

        return self.value + other


print(Example(3) + 5)
print(Example(4) + Example(2))

# 8
# 6
```

Comment: Cool things you learn everyday!

Comment: Learning from each other ^u^